# C# entity framework Querying stored procedure error "Culture is not supported"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im trying to query data from a database which contains some korean text. The same works with other DB which doesnt have any korean information. Should i set some culture info? The DB collation i found is **Korean_Wansung_Unicode_CI_AS**

```
using (DBModel data = new DBModel())
{
  //command and parameters prepared here  
  var SqlCommand = "ProcedureName @LastUpdateDate, @LastUpdateTS";
   var SqlParams = new SqlParameter[]
   {
     new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@LastUpdateDate",  Value =lastDatetime, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input },
     new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@LastUpdateTS",  Value =lastTS, Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input }
    };
  return data.Database.SqlQuery<BP>(SqlCommand, SqlParams).ToList();
}
```

This **Database.SqlQuery** is throwing **CultureNotFoundException** as below

> Culture is not supported.
>
> Parameter name: culture
>
> 66578 (0x10412) is an invalid culture identifier.

```
at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Int32 culture)
   at System.Globalization.CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo(Int32 culture)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.LinearIndexOf(String fieldName, CompareOptions compareOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.IndexOf(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.TryGetColumnOrdinalFromReader(DbDataReader storeDataReader, String columnName, Int32& ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.CreateColumnMapFromReaderAndClrType(DbDataReader reader, Type type, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InternalTranslate[TElement](DbDataReader reader, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, EntitySet& entitySet, TypeUsage& edmType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__68()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__67()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass14`1.<ExecuteSqlQuery>b__13()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I tried the same with the plain old way to retrive the data to a datatable, somehow it works. So what need to be set in EF?

```
            var SqlCommand = "exec ProcedureName '2018-11-11 16:30:00', 163000";                   

            string constring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString();
            SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlCommand, con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: It may because the stored procedure may be requiring 'Culture' parameter but you are not providing it.

Comment: no, there is no such parameter.

Comment: ok please provide full code for the comments section '//command and parameters prepared here' and also the stored procedure which you have (if any)

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: this is interesting; this is all internal plumbing code - it *looks* like EF (or rather: the comparer, which EF uses) simply hates the culture that has been provided; I'm trying to see where that comes from, but: what culture is this machine running in?

Comment: normal en-US, but i found that the DB collation is Korean_Wansung_Unicode_CI_AS. probably something about this?

Comment: the *only* code-path I can find that doesn't pass -1 is `SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal`, which passes `_defaultLCID`; this comes from the `_parser.DefaultLCID` - which looks like it comes from the TDS stream (an "env" change, type 5); so indeed, my initial thought is that: SqlClient (not specifically EF) *hates* your SQL Server's collation!

Comment: so what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The LCID here *appears* to be set in the TDS parser - in particular `TdsParser.TryProcessEnvChange`; that means there isn't anything you can do *in your C# code* to change things.

All I can offer is two suggestions:

1. try to install a relevant Korean language pack onto the machine that you're querying from; it could be that right now it is unable to resolve the culture, but that installing the language pack into Windows helps it understand - **untested**
2. see if you can change the database collation; now obviously, this is a *huge* change that has massive impact, so shouldn't be done lightly - and ideally only after all other approaches have failed

The third option, of course, might be to see if the EF or SqlClient folks (overlapping teams) are responsive on github; they're under dotnet/corefx. The public github is mostly ".NET Core" however, so a great place to start would be to confirm that the same problem happens on .NET Core; if so, it'll be much easier to engage with people.

Disclaimer: everything here is from hacking through the call tree, and I *do not* make any claim to be authoritative on this.

Comment: I tried using normal ADO SqlConnection and it works. so why only EF have issue?

Comment: @Hybridzz oh, that makes it even more interesting then - and frankly, it makes it a question for the EF team.

Comment: hmm. i have updated the question. By the way i tried installing the language to the machine. still EF way is throwing error. I am unable to do 2 as it is not my DB.